# Difference between LinkedList<T> clear and new LinkedList<T> in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading

Why would this code:

```
public synchronized void update() {
        for(T event : eventQueue)
        {
            processEvent(event);
        }
        events = eventQueue;
        eventQueue = new LinkedList<T>();
}
```

run differently to this code:

```
public synchronized void update() {
            for(T event : eventQueue)
            {
                processEvent(event);
            }
            events = eventQueue;
            eventQueue.clear();
}
```

The first version works perfectly fine, however the second does not. The `eventQueue.clear();` causes the app not to receive any events and finely crashes with a `Concurrent Exception`.

My app has two threads. The UI thread and the GameLoop thread. The UI thread adds events to the `eventQueue` like so:

```
public synchronized void addEvent(T newEvent) {
            eventQueue.add(newEvent);
}
```

The GameLoop thread calls the update method to get a copy (called `events`) of the `eventQueue`.

All the code can be viewed from this website: http://entropyinteractive.com/2011/02/game-engine-design-input/

This seems kinda mysterious to me, since I thought `eventQueue = new LinkedList<T>();` and `eventQueue.clear();` would both result in an empty `LinkedList`? I believe it has something todo with establishing a new reference (But why?!).

Comment: The first set of code would execute faster than the second one and yeah if the `LinkedList` is structurally being changed while being clearing off , it might throw ConcurrentModificationException...

Comment: @JohnVint *Concurrent Exception*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ConcurrentModificationException?

Comment: @JohnVint looks like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in this code:

```
public LinkedList<T> getEvents()
{
    return events;
}
```

You're returning the original list, not a copy. If you then `clear()` that list, you'll cause issues because you're removing things from the list (and more important, changing the size of the list) while the other thread is using it.

Note that this function isn't `synchronized`, so you can't even safely return a copy from it, because the original list could change while you're copying it (changing a reference is [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operation), so it's safe to do that in your `update()` method).

You could return a copy from a synchronized method, like this:

```
public synchronized LinkedList<T> getEvents()
{
    return new LinkedList<T>(events);
}
```

But that introduces an unnecessary copy and lock. Whether that matters depends on if you care more about [defensive coding](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15) or performance requirements. I assume they're doing it this way for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem

```
  events = eventQueue;
  eventQueue.clear()
```

Once you assign `events = eventQueue` you are escaping the reference of `eventQueue` to the public via

```
public LinkedList<T> getEvents()
{
    return events;
}
```

One thread can be iterating over the `getEvents()` queue which actually is `eventQueue` and another thread can be invoking `addEvent` and since the `synchronized` in addEvent no longer matches with the iterator of `getEvents()` you will get the comodification.

My suggestion is if you really want to publish your events do it with a new collection.

```
  events = new LinkedList<T>(eventQueue);
  eventQueue.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not protect *all* uses of `eventQueue`, like handing out references in `getEvents()`, you should try `ConcurrentLinkedList`.